# order by len() en linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

**esta es mi consulta en el servidor sql y todo funciona bien**

```
select * from DetalleNotas
order by len(ColProduct), ColProduct

PROCT1
PROCT2
PROCT3
PROCT4
PROCT5
PROCT6
PROCT7
PROCT8
PROCT9
PROCT10
```

**pero quiero mi consulta en linq**

***Intenté esto y no funciona***

```
var product = (from d in db.Product
                orderby len(d.ColProduct), d.ColProduct
                select new
                {
                    product= d.product
                });
```

***solo esta consulta funciona***

```
var product = (from d in db.Product
                orderby d.ColProduct
                select new
                {
                    product= d.product
                });
```

***Este es el resultado de mi consulta funcional***

```
PROCT1
PROCT10
PROCT2
PROCT3
PROCT4
PROCT5
PROCT6
PROCT7
PROCT8
PROCT9
```

Comment: `len` es un keyword de SQL no de C#. El equivalente en C# sería `.Length` como menciona Cloruro de Sodio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quizá quieras hacer el `orderby` por:

```
orderby d.ColProduct.Length
```

Si `d.ColProduct` es de tipo `string`, debajo un ejemplo:

```
var s = new List<string> { "hola", "hello33", "hillos" };

var T = from e in s orderby e.Length select e;
var T2 = s.OrderBy(x => x.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Con query syntax: ");
foreach (var k in T) 
    Console.WriteLine(k);

Console.WriteLine("\nCon method syntax:");
foreach (var k in T2)
    Console.WriteLine(k);
```

El ejemplo de arriba lo hice sobre un `List<string>`, pero es lo mismo si haces la modificación que te mencioné hace un momento, este es el resultado que me arroja:

> ```
> Con query syntax: 
> hola
> hillos
> hello33
>
> Con method syntax:
> hola
> hillos
> hello33
> ```

Aplicandolo a tu consulta sería:

```
var product = (from d in db.Product
               orderby d.ColProduct.Length select new {
                 product= d.product
              });
```

Aquí te dejo un [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tr0762) para que pruebes, saludos!! :)